# Match value between two sheets and copy corresponding value to initial sheet twice

Tags: vba, excel

I have one workbook with four sheets - one Consolidated sheet that draws all information from the other items (Sheet2-4). The Consolidated sheet will be used as the source file for another Excel sheet that will be used to edit and update fields that could not be populated from the below reports (Sheet2-4). I am unable to use Access or another database type do to constraints beyond my control.

```
Sheet1 : Consolidated_Sheet  
Sheet2 : Incentive_Report_Raw_Data  
Sheet3 : Offer_Report_Raw_Data  
Sheet4 : SQR_Report_Raw_Data
```

**Step 1:** Integrate Data From Sheet3 to Consolidated Sheet - Works

```
Sub InitialMigration()
Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Offer_Report_Raw_Data").Columns("B")
Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet").Columns("D")

sourceColumn.Copy [targetColumn]

Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Offer_Report_Raw_Data").Columns("AH")
Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet").Columns("H")

sourceColumn.Copy [targetColumn]

Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Offer_Report_Raw_Data").Columns("AV")
Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet").Columns("L")

sourceColumn.Copy [targetColumn]

Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Offer_Report_Raw_Data").Columns("AW")
Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet").Columns("M")

sourceColumn.Copy [targetColumn]

Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Offer_Report_Raw_Data").Columns("D")
Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet").Columns("N")

sourceColumn.Copy [targetColumn]

Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Offer_Report_Raw_Data").Columns("I")
Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet").Columns("O")

sourceColumn.Copy [targetColumn]

Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Offer_Report_Raw_Data").Columns("AS")
Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet").Columns("P")

sourceColumn.Copy [targetColumn]

Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Offer_Report_Raw_Data").Columns("BC")
Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet").Columns("W")

sourceColumn.Copy [targetColumn]

Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Offer_Report_Raw_Data").Columns("AO")
Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet").Columns("Z")

sourceColumn.Copy [targetColumn]

Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Offer_Report_Raw_Data").Columns("AN")
Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet").Columns("AB")

sourceColumn.Copy [targetColumn]

Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Offer_Report_Raw_Data").Columns("AK")
Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet").Columns("Y")

sourceColumn.Copy [targetColumn]

Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Offer_Report_Raw_Data").Columns("AM") 'Pricing
Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet").Columns("AD")

sourceColumn.Copy [targetColumn]

Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Offer_Report_Raw_Data").Columns("F") 'Campaign Owner
Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet").Columns("I")

sourceColumn.Copy [targetColumn]

Set sourceColumn = Worksheets("Offer_Report_Raw_Data").Columns("AG") 'Product
Set targetColumn = Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet").Columns("F")

sourceColumn.Copy [targetColumn]
End Sub
```

**Step 2:** I Need to match value from Consolidated_Sheet (Column U) to that in SQR (Column J) then copy value in same row SQR (Column F) to the corresponding row of initial value in Consolidated_Sheet (Column O).
 Match (CS-U) to (SQR-J) then copy (SQR-F) to (CS-O).

Note: The rows on the two different sheets Do Not match.

I have attempted this with limited success on a small scale - one row and it works, but I cannot find a way to make it work amongst a larger dataset - (~2,000+ rows). I found this on the internet and this is the closest I could get to what I was looking for - I honestly don't know if I asked the correct way.

```
Sub Submission()
Set wks1 = Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet")
Set wks2 = Worksheets("SQR_Report_Raw_Data")


With wks1

End With
If wks1.Range("U") = wks2.Range("J") Then
wks2.Range("F").Copy wks1.Range("O") '<< cpy to 2nd WS
End If
End Sub
```

**Step 3:** The requirement from the previous exercise would be necessary between the Consolidated_Sheet and the Incentive_Report_Raw_Data.

Please note also that these Raw Data Sheets will be updated weekly and I would lie this to be able to continuously update everything. Ideally in a step by step process.

Comment: Are the values being used for looking up information on other sheets unique, or could there be multiple corresponding rows?

Comment: The values are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Your first part is functional, but can be shortened quite a bit (and so made easier to maintain) if you use a small Sub to do the actual copying:

```
Sub InitialMigration()
    CopyColumn "B", "D"
    CopyColumn "AH", "H"
    CopyColumn "AV", "L"
    CopyColumn "AW", "M"
    CopyColumn "D", "N"
    CopyColumn "I", "O"
    CopyColumn "AS", "P"
    CopyColumn "BC", "W"
    CopyColumn "AO", "Z"
    CopyColumn "AN", "AB"
    '...ETC ETC
End Sub

'Utility sub: Copy col letter S to col letter D
Sub CopyColumn(S As String, D As String)
    Worksheets("Offer_Report_Raw_Data").Columns(S).Copy _
            Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet").Columns(D)
End Sub
```

The last part is a bit more complicated but in the example below all of the logic is in the `DoLookup` Sub, so you can call this repeatedly from `Submission`, with different parameters for:

- the column you want to look up
- which column you want to check that against
- where to pick the value from in the event of a match
- which column to put that value into

Here's the code:

```
Sub Submission()

    Dim wksCS As Worksheet, wksSQR As Worksheet

    Set wksCS = Worksheets("Consolidated_Sheet")
    Set wksSQR = Worksheets("SQR_Report_Raw_Data")

    'look up colU against colJ - copy match from ColF to ColO
    DoLookup wksCS.Columns("U"), wksSQR.Columns("J"), "F", "O"

    'add more lookups here....


End Sub

'Utility: for each value in SrcCol, check MatchCol for a match.
'  If found, copy the value from Col 'ValCol' on the matched row to Col 'DestCol' on
'   the consolidation sheet.
Sub DoLookup(SrcCol As Range, MatchCol As Range, ValCol As String, DestCol As String)
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngMatch As Range, c As Range, v, m
    'just work with the "used" parts of the match columns
    Set rngSrc = Application.Intersect(SrcCol, SrcCol.Parent.UsedRange)
    Set rngMatch = Application.Intersect(MatchCol, MatchCol.Parent.UsedRange)

    For Each c In rngSrc.Cells
        v = c.Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            m = Application.Match(v, rngMatch, 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                c.EntireRow.Cells(1, DestCol).Value = _
                   rngMatch.Cells(m).EntireRow.Cells(1, ValCol)
            Else
                'decide what you want to do here...
                c.EntireRow.Cells(1, DestCol).Value = "No match!"
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Good luck!

Comment: It is a 424 Error that highlights that particular line.

Comment: It is a 424 Error that highlights that particular line. I attempted to rerun it and it worked correctly, but it highlighted the "C.EntireRow.Cells - (1, ValCol)" as a 1004 Error.

Comment: What are the values of `DestCol` and `ValCol` when it fails ?

Comment: It may be an error on my end. Initial Do Lookup should remain as written(with columns being changed to suit lookup needs). The second set of code from your explanation believes the necessary data is on the consolidated sheet, when it comes from the SQR Sheet and needs to be copied to the Consolidated sheet.  Val Col should be the column on SQR Sheet from which the data is copied and Dest should be the location on Consolidated Sheet where it is copied to. Please confirm or correct.